# How to create a login in console where I authenticate using an username and password stored in a file c#

Tags: c#

So, I need to create a login mechanism within the visual studio console authenticating clients using usernames and passwords I have stored in a file, here's the content of the file:

1;user1;mail1@gmail.com;username1;pass1 2;user2;mail2@gmail.com;username2;pass2 3;user3;mail3@gmail.com;username3;pass3 4;user4;mail4@gmail.com;username4;pass4 5;user5;mail5@gmail.com;username5;pass5

I've never worked with c# before.

Thank you in advance!

I've tried the following code but I'm getting an exception null saying arr[] is null:

```cs
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:/User.txt");
string[][] arr = new string[lines.Length][];
string username, password;
string fileuser = lines[3];
string filepassw = lines[4];
int userpos = 3;
int passwpos = 4;
bool isValideUser = false;
for (int x = 3; x >= 1; x--)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have " + x + " attempt/s.");
    Console.Write("Enter Username>> ");
    username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Password>> ");
    password = Console.ReadLine();
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        if (username.Equals(arr[row][userpos]) && password.Equals(arr[row][passwpos]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + lines[1] + "!");
            isValideUser = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isValideUser)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input.");
        if (x != 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Try Again.");
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        else if (x.Equals(1))
        {
            Console.Write("Goodbye!");
            break;
        }
    }
    else
        break;
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: arr is null because you only declared it, you didn't initialize it (put values in it)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How can I put there the values of the lines[] array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to populate `arr` with values, I would change `arr` to type `List<string[]>` and then populate the `List` with values from the file using `foreach` and `string.Split()`:

Insted of :

```
string[][] arr = new string[lines.Length][];
```

use:

```
List<string[]> arr = new List<string[]>();
foreach (var item in lines)
{
     arr.Add(item.Split(';'));
}
```

With this modification the program runs fine.